# Force rebuild docker container to rebuild server conf file?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I was trying to edit my /app/alerta.conf file in my docker container on ubuntu, and accidentally deleted all the contents inside the file.

Now when I go to run `sudo docker exec -ti 0c24c2e72716 alerta blackouts` to execute a command for my application inside the docker container, it gives me a long list of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/bin/alerta", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1656, in invoke
    super().invoke(ctx)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alertaclient/cli.py", line 55, in cli
    config = Config(config_file)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alertaclient/config.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.parser.read(os.path.expanduser(self.options['config_file']))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 1082, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: '/app/alerta.conf', line: 1
"PLUGINS = ['blackout_regex']\n"
```

I know the reason for this is because the `/app/alerta.conf` file is corrupted. How can I safely **rebuild this docker image** in a way that will correctly recreate this file and ignore the changes I made?

I tried restarting the docker container using `sudo docker restart alerta-web` however this does not rebuild the container correctly. When I try to rebuild the container using `sudo docker build --no-cache alerta/alerta-web` it gives me an "unable to prepare context: path "alerta/alerta-web" not found" error.

Comment: In should usually be safe to `docker stop && docker rm` a container and then `docker run` a new one; a correctly-configured container shouldn't be keeping anything in the container temporary filesystem that could be lost.  You shouldn't need to rebuild the image for this case, just recreate the container.

Comment: I removed and re-ran the docker containers and now I am running into a very vague Error: Failed to get config from http://localhost:8080/api/config. Reason: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://localhost:8080/api/config error. The only thing I changed is restarting these containers so the error must lie somewhere here, but I am not sure where.

My boss also ran into this error before and he said he fixed it by "restarting all Docker stuff"

Comment: If you can [edit] the question to include a [mcve] that would be helpful.  What does the application source look like, and how would you build the image and start the container on a clean system?